# Collection view after Table view

Tags: ios, swift

I'm building an iOS app and I want the home page to be a collection of information the user can scroll through.

The contents are:

- Greeting label
- Table with a variable number of rows (with a header label on top)
- Grid (maybe with 3 or 4 columns) showing the user's friends

Roughly speaking, I want to have a UILabel, then below I want a UITableView, and finally a UICollectionView. The user should be able to scroll the whole screen (e.g. I don't want the table view to scroll alone at any point, the table view should have a height to accommodate all existing cells).

What is the best way to approach this?

Comment: create a UIScrollView with a container view in it.  place the UILabel,UITabelView and UICollectionView inside the container

Comment: this tutorial with the UIScrollView should help https://spin.atomicobject.com/2014/03/05/uiscrollview-autolayout-ios/

Comment: Use only one collection view. On the header place the label and the table view...then the cells.